# What does the p letter in booleans stand for?

Tags: c, naming-conventions, tcl

I'm working on some C and TCL libraries which keeps referring to booleans using a convention of addin a p to the end of the variable name, i.e.

```
set is_registered_p 0
# do stuff
if { $is_registered_p } { 
    #do stuff
}
```

I found this in multiple files and from multiple sources, so I thought it have to be a convention of some kind.

Comment: Maybe it stands for predicate?

Comment: perhaps a language issue: poolean?->

Comment: I have found  # Check if the registered_user_p procedure finds him, so maybe `procedure`

Comment: no it's not a proc, also I found this in tcl and C, it can't be a mistake

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most likely thing is that it stands for “***P***redicate” (i.e., a condition that can be evaluated to yield a boolean value) but its not a convention that's particularly common among most Tcl programmers.

If someone's using the convention, you might expect to see it with the names of both variables and commands; in the former case, they'll hold booleans and in the latter case they'll return booleans when executed.

Answer (score 5):

My guess would be [predicate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_%28mathematical_logic%29).

There's also [a convention in LISP](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node69.html) to use a trailing P for predicate functions.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like adding `p` to the end of the name is a common LISP [naming convention](http://www.webweasel.com/lisp/doc/cl06.htm) for predicates which would be consistent with the use you have shown.

Answer (score 4):

A predicate is a function that tests for some condition involving its arguments and returns nil if the condition is false, or some non-nil value if the condition is true.One may think of a predicate as producing a Boolean value, where nil stands for false and anything else stands for true.

By convention, the names of predicates usually end in the letter p (which stands for ``predicate'').